# MQTT getting full topic params

Tags: c#, mqtt

I am using `Mqtt` [Emitter](https://emitter.io/) for my application.The think I want to do is getting params where I put the `"+"`.
For instance;

```
   emitter.On("input/+/sensor", (channel, msg) =>
      {//after emitter publish the message, I want to know which company
       //is publishing the message by knowing the value of "+".
         Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msg));
      });
  emitter.Publish("input/company1/sensor", "hellooo");
```

I'm open to different ideas..

Comment: whatdo you mean with: ***getting params where I put the "+".***

Comment: I mean, as above example, the publish method which have `input/company1/sensor` topic will catch `emitter.On` method.But inside `emitter.On` method, I don't know full path of the topic.the thing I want to do in above example is catching `company1` instead `+` sign.Hope I can clearly tell you.

Comment: `+` is single segment wildcard, the OP wants to know exactly what topic was matched. Looking at the Emitter doc it doesn't look possible if `msg` is just the payload

Comment: acording to emitter doc, I can not take the what I want.I asked if somebody has encountered same problem like I do.